# Помогите составить MySQL-запрос

Tags: mysql

У меня есть такая SQL-таблица с названием muted, людьми, у которых имеется активный Mute (затычка в чате).

```
id   name    author    time    reason 
43   "John"  "Mike"     15    "Capslock"
...
46   "John"  "Looney"   30    "Flood"
47   "Ray"   "Mike"     45    "Capslock + Flood"
```

Скажем так, что мут юзера имеет эффект резонанса и объединяется с уже существующими. Это значит, что если у John'a есть 15 минут мута и ещё добавили 30-минутный **за что-то ещё**, в общем у него уже 45.

**Вопрос:**

Как сделать запрос, в котором значение колонки time уменьшится на единицу только в первой попавшейся строке с именем John, чтобы не уменьшить time второй, третьей ... и других его колонок в других выданных мутах? (когда time = 0, он удалится, это к сведению)

P/S: Я мог бы сделать просто одну строку на пользователя и с добавлением мута увеличивать значение time, но мне нужна также и история того, кто выдал и по какой причине мут снова, совмещать ещё со временем и хранением этого всего, я не нашел другого варианта. Спасибо.

Comment: LIMIT не подойдет?

Comment: Можете пожалуйста уточнить, что вы имели ввиду, я новичок в горизонте баз данных

Comment: В конце запроса напишите LIMIT 1.

Comment: UPDATE muted SET time = ('текущий time' - 1) WHERE name = "John" LIMIT 1;

Выходит нечто такое, я правильно перевёл ваши мысли?

Comment: Да, правильно...

Comment: Простите за уточнения, но кажется это работает, мне начинает нравится за такие вещи SQL =)

Как мне пометить Вас, что вы смогли найти решение моего вопроса?

Comment: Только что добавил ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам достаточно добавить `LIMIT 1` в конце запроса. Вот пример:

```
CREATE TABLE temp(num INTEGER);
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (1), (2), (3);
UPDATE temp SET num = num + 1 LIMIT 1;
```

До изменения:

> num
>   1
>   2
>   3

После изменения:

> num
>   2
>   2
>   3